# Почему не правильно работает "or" в Python?

Tags: python

```
Имя_системы = ["К1", "К2", "В1, К2, К3", "К3", "Т3", ""]
Сантехнические_приборы = 8792
Рабочий_набор = []
for n in range(len(Имя_системы)):
    if "В" or "Т" or "К" in Имя_системы[n]: Рабочий_набор.insert(n, Сантехнические_приборы)
    else: Рабочий_набор.insert(n, 0)

print(Рабочий_набор)
```

Результат: [8792, 8792, 8792, 8792, 8792, 8792]
Хотя в конце списка должно быть значение 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас неверно составлено условие.
Вы проверяете если "B" истина или если "T" истина или если "К" в Имя_системы[n]. Любая не пустая строка - истина, соответственно условие всегда истинно. Самое простое что можно сделать переписать условие следующим образом:

```
if "В" in Имя_системы[n] or "Т" in Имя_системы[n] or "К" in Имя_системы[n]:
    Рабочий_набор.insert(n, Сантехнические_приборы)
else:
    Рабочий_набор.insert(n, 0)
```

Comment: А если не самым простым образом сделать, это как будет?

Comment: @NurJ `if any(letter in Имя_системы[n] for letter in "KBT"):`